How do I extract data from a tcp transmission from a .net application to another .net application using python?
I am intercepting a tcp transmission of an app I use, but I need to get the data into a table (excel or db). I can read the message but it also conatains a lot of gibberish (that is probably useful to the original program but I only need the information). I was able to extract some data, but only when searching for patterns, but I can't predict the content, so I need a better solution. I was thinking of splitting up the input but the content doesn't have a fixed lenght.
Generally I want the information "Time", "EventName", "Round", "Classes", "ClassesShort" and "CombinedName" from all entries.
Can someone help me or suggest another way to approach this?
              System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yesthisisapublictoken]]   _items_size_version                                                    
   
   RDisplayBoard.Communication, Version=1.0.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   -DisplayBoard.Communication.Packets.LoadLayout   #LayoutBase+<Channel>k__BackingField$LayoutBase+<FileName>k__BackingField LayoutBase+<Name>k__BackingField*LayoutBase+<SendCurrenView>k__BackingField            Schedule
   +Layout_0d805b91-d3a6-4702-82be-b266da8ccf93    .DisplayBoard.Communication.Packets.SetProperty   <Channel>k__BackingField<LayoutName>k__BackingField<ElementName>k__BackingField<PropertyName>k__BackingField<Value>k__BackingField         
      Header1   Text   8yesthisisaeventname             
      Header2         yesthisisaplaceandtime            
        ListTitle         yesthisisalisttitle           
      ListTitleWithDate       yesthisisalisttitleandthedate             
      SessionName           yesthisisadate              
   "   List#   Data $   
   -DisplayBoard.Communication.Packets.ShowLayout   ClearOthers#LayoutBase+<Channel>k__BackingField$LayoutBase+<FileName>k__BackingField LayoutBase+<Name>k__BackingField*LayoutBase+<SendCurrenView>k__BackingField          
    
   &   NSystem.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yesthisisapublictoken$   #DisplayBoard.Communication.ListData   <Table>k__BackingFieldSystem.Data.DataTable&          '   '   System.Data.DataTable   DataTable.RemotingVersionDataTable.RemotingFormatDataTable.TableNameDataTable.NamespaceDataTable.PrefixDataTable.CaseSensitiveDataTable.caseSensitiveAmbientDataTable.LocaleLCIDDataTable.MinimumCapacityDataTable.NestedInDataSetDataTable.TypeNameDataTable.RepeatableElementDataTable.ExtendedPropertiesDataTable.Columns.Count!DataTable.DataColumn_0.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_0.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_0.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_0.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_0.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_0.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_0.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_0.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_0.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_0.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_0.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_0.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_0.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_0.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_0.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_0.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_0.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_0.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_0.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_1.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_1.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_1.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_1.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_1.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_1.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_1.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_1.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_1.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_1.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_1.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_1.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_1.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_1.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_1.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_1.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_1.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_1.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_1.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_2.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_2.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_2.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_2.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_2.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_2.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_2.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_2.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_2.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_2.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_2.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_2.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_2.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_2.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_2.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_2.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_2.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_2.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_2.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_3.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_3.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_3.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_3.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_3.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_3.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_3.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_3.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_3.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_3.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_3.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_3.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_3.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_3.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_3.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_3.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_3.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_3.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_3.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_4.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_4.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_4.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_4.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_4.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_4.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_4.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_4.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_4.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_4.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_4.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_4.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_4.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_4.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_4.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_4.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_4.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_4.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_4.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_5.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_5.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_5.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_5.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_5.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_5.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_5.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_5.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_5.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_5.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_5.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_5.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_5.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_5.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_5.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_5.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_5.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_5.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_5.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_6.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_6.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_6.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_6.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_6.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_6.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_6.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_6.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_6.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_6.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_6.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_6.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_6.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_6.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_6.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_6.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_6.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_6.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_6.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_7.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_7.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_7.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_7.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_7.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_7.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_7.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_7.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_7.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_7.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_7.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_7.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_7.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_7.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_7.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_7.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_7.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_7.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_7.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_8.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_8.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_8.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_8.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_8.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_8.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_8.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_8.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_8.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_8.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_8.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_8.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_8.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_8.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_8.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_8.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_8.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_8.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_8.ExtendedProperties!DataTable.DataColumn_9.ColumnName DataTable.DataColumn_9.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_9.Prefix$DataTable.DataColumn_9.ColumnMapping"DataTable.DataColumn_9.AllowDBNull$DataTable.DataColumn_9.AutoIncrement(DataTable.DataColumn_9.AutoIncrementStep(DataTable.DataColumn_9.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_9.Caption#DataTable.DataColumn_9.DefaultValueDataTable.DataColumn_9.ReadOnly DataTable.DataColumn_9.MaxLengthDataTable.DataColumn_9.DataType"DataTable.DataColumn_9.XmlDataType!DataTable.DataColumn_9.SimpleType#DataTable.DataColumn_9.DateTimeMode+DataTable.DataColumn_9.AutoIncrementCurrent!DataTable.DataColumn_9.Expression)DataTable.DataColumn_9.ExtendedProperties"DataTable.DataColumn_10.ColumnName!DataTable.DataColumn_10.NamespaceDataTable.DataColumn_10.Prefix%DataTable.DataColumn_10.ColumnMapping#DataTable.DataColumn_10.AllowDBNull%DataTable.DataColumn_10.AutoIncrement)DataTable.DataColumn_10.AutoIncrementStep)DataTable.DataColumn_10.AutoIncrementSeedDataTable.DataColumn_10.Caption$DataTable.DataColumn_10.DefaultValue DataTable.DataColumn_10.ReadOnly!DataTable.DataColumn_10.MaxLength DataTable.DataColumn_10.DataType#DataTable.DataColumn_10.XmlDataType"DataTable.DataColumn_10.SimpleType$DataTable.DataColumn_10.DateTimeMode,DataTable.DataColumn_10.AutoIncrementCurrent"DataTable.DataColumn_10.Expression*DataTable.DataColumn_10.ExtendedPropertiesDataTable_0.ConstraintsDataTable_0.Rows.CountDataTable_0.Records.CountDataTable_0.RowStatesDataTable_0.RecordsDataTable_0.NullBitsDataTable_0.RowErrorsDataTable_0.ColumnErrors                                                                                      System.VersionSystem.Data.SerializationFormat&   System.Data.PropertyCollection&   System.Data.MappingType&          System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Data.MappingType&        System.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.UnitySerializationHolderSystem.Data.DataSetDateTime&      System.Collections.ArrayListSystem.Collections.BitArraySystem.Collections.ArrayListSystem.Collections.ArrayListSystem.Collections.HashtableSystem.Collections.Hashtable&    (   System.Data.SerializationFormat   value__ &      *      *       *      2    *       +      ,   Index
    *   System.Data.MappingType   value__ &                         ,       0       1       *   
System.Data.DataSetDateTime   value__ &                 *   
4   Selected
    *                       4       0       9       *   
            *   
<   Time
    *                       <       0       A       *   
            *   
D       EventName
    *                       D       0       A       *   
            *   
L   
EventNameInfo
    *                       L       0       A       *   
            *   
T   EventNameWithoutInfo
    *                       T       0       A       *   
            *   
\   Round
    *                       \       0       A       *   
            *   
d   
EventRound
    *                       d       0       A       *   
            *   
l   Classes
    *                       l       0       A       *   
            *   
t   ClassesShort
    *                       t       0       A       *   
            *   
|   CombinedName
    *                       |       0       A       *   
}               *   
                                   (   System.Version   _Major_Minor_Build  _Revision           +   System.Data.PropertyCollection   
LoadFactorVersionComparerHashCodeProviderHashSizeKeysValues   System.Collections.IComparer$System.Collections.IHashCodeProvider&   Q8?    

           0   System.UnitySerializationHolder   Data   UnityTypeAssemblyName 
    *   1   0      System.Int32      Kmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yesthisisapublictoken9   0      System.Boolean        A   0      
System.String             System.Collections.ArrayList   _items_size_version                  System.Collections.BitArray   m_arraym_length_version                                                 System.Collections.Hashtable   
LoadFactorVersionComparerHashCodeProviderHashSizeKeysValues   System.Collections.IComparer$System.Collections.IHashCodeProviderQ8?    

                 Q8?    

                                      $I                                                   
                                                   
                                                                                  10:30   10:30   10:40   11:00   11:00   11:00   11:00   11:00         EventNameNumber1   
EventNameNumber2   EventNameNumber3   EventNameNumber4   EventNameNumber5   EventNameNumber6   EventNameNumber7   EventNameNumber8                                                                                          
Round1   Round2   
Round3      Round4   Round5   Round6   Round7   Round8         EventRound1   EventRound2   EventRound3   
EventRound4   EventRound5   EventRound6   EventRound7   EventRound8         Classes1   Classes2   Classes3      Classes4   
Classes5   
Classes6   
Classes7   
Classes8         ClassesShort1   ClassesShort2   ClassesShort3   ClassesShort4   ClassesShort5   ClassesShort6   ClassesShort7   ClassesShort8         CombinedName1   CombinedName2   CombinedName3   CombinedName4   "CombinedName5   "CombinedName6   !CombinedName7   !CombinedName8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

I tried using patterns, but I can't predict the content, I need a solution that is independent from the content of the table (tho still letters, number, etc. but no gibberish).
